# jQuery Syntax assistance filter Select Options out (hide) via textbox keystroke

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax

I have code that shows or hides elements according to filter.
I need help including a condition where if the browser is IE then according to the filter wrap the unmatching elements with a SPAN and hide them, and the other way around - unspan and show.
 I do not know the syntax and I failed repeatedly.
I'm really stuck, please help (if you can by tweaking my code)
My Code:

```
    <!--This is where I filter the ListBox (select) >> (option) elements via keystrokes -->
<!--Via jQuery on my Listbox control I add a css class so I can work with it here - class ".srcItem" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            var elemSrc = document.getElementById("<%=srcBox.ClientID%>");
            $(elemSrc).find("option").addClass("srcItem");
        }
        );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
     function () {
         var $users = $('.srcItem');
         $('#usrSearch').keyup(function () {
             $users.show(); //THis is regular jQuery that works only in Chrome

                 return;
             }
             var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

             //Below is regular jQuery that works only in Chrome

             $users.show().filter(function () {
                 var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                 return !~text.indexOf(val);

             }).hide();

         });
     }
   );

</script>
```

Comment: i think you are using an JQuery version no supports IE Browser, visit jquery.com to get a full version

Comment: It's the Internet Explorer that doesn't support display:none; on an "option" element within "select" element.

Comment: `show` and `hide` can be problematic, not sure if this is your problem though.

Comment: WHat I'm asking for is a code adjustment that will wrap the option element with a span element incase the browser is IE.

Comment: try set onclick at <span> to hide <option>

Comment: There is no span yet... Please read my comment.

Comment: i see <option> has class=srcItem, in script: set $('.srcItem').hide(); at trigger state

Comment: var $user  is not global variable, so remove "var" for valid in function mention it

Comment: There is no ID. it's a class set on an array or elements. The hide occurs on filter function. What you are suggesting is already happening but it works only in Chrome. Please read the code in full. There is no point commenting if you do not fully understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The folks in jQuery forums where very helpful and solved this.
Here is the Fiddle that contains the solution:
[JakeCigarFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/vsjerbx6/)

HTML:

```
    <input id="usrSearch" type="search" placeholder="Filter..." style="width: 154px; height: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 1px; border-width:4px; border-radius:10px;" />

 <select name="leftSrcBox" id="srcBox" style="border-width: 4px; padding: 4px; border-radius: 10px; width: 200px; height: 400px;" size="4">
<option class="srcItem" value="72371">Adam Sandler</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="95310">Adam Boldwin</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="54288">Adam Eve</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="90217">Boris Johnson</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="74724">Boris Bekker</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="54536">Bob Dylan</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="36202">Carl Sagan</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="5975">Carl Booker</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="38307">Cory Sanders</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="92817">David Whealan</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="8730">David Hurst</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="30775">Danny Sanders</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="78253">Dan Dover</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="95183">Ethan Jenkins</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="31344">Ethan Hunt</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="57950">Edgar Pugh</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="36384">Ed Wilkins</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="36715">Fred Jefferson</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="65292">Freddy Mercury</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="47803">Gina Davis</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="48991">Giovanni Bonucci</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="54213">Heather Stevens</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="45948">Hector Wallas</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="44818">Igor Biskan</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="95863">Iggy Pop</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="48637">Jacob Allen</option>
<option class="srcItem" value="45658">Jacob Collins</option>

 </select>
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {
      var $select = $("#srcBox").clone();
      $('#usrSearch').keyup(function() {
        var currentValue=$("#srcBox").val();
        var search = squeeze($(this).val());
       $("#srcBox").html($select.children().clone().filter(function() {
         return squeeze($(this).text()).match( search )
      })).val(currentValue)
   });
});

 function squeeze(v) {
   return v.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
 }
```

JakeCigar's Explanation:

```
       $(function() { // wait till the DOM is ready
         var $select = $("#srcBox").clone(); // save off an untouched copy of the select.
    $('#usrSearch').keyup(function() {
        var currentValue=$("#srcBox").val(); // remember what was selected
        var search = squeeze($(this).val());  // squeeze what they typed in
        // this is where is gets complex. 
        // set the srcBox to a new clone of the clone that was filtered 
        // then set the value back to what was selected
        $("#srcBox").html($select.children().clone().filter(function() {
            return squeeze($(this).text()).match( search )
        })).val(currentValue)
     });
  });

  function squeeze(v) { // since you need to squeeze both the text and the option values 
                              // I moved it out to a function
      return v.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
}
 //No need to write special code for IE, because it is classic jQuery code.
```